# A reset button for tkinter entries, looped inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter-entry

I've successfully looped the textvariable for all the entries created to point to DoubleVar(), and its working properly. The problem arose when i tried creating reset button for all the entries. from my code as shown, the program runs, doesn't raise any error, and the values in the entries are not cleared. thanks in advance :)

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file = 'background.png')
cc = DoubleVar()
cc.set('##')
dr =Label(root, text='helo world')
sd = []
y = -1
dr.pack()
Entry(root, textvariable =cc).pack()
def clear():
    cc.set('')
    for i in sd:
        i['textvariable'] = DoubleVar().set('')
def create():
    global  y
    y +=1
    sd.append(Entry(root, width =5))
    for i in sd:
        i["textvariable"] = DoubleVar()
    sd[y].pack()
Button(root, text = 'push', command = clear).pack()
Button(root, text = 'create', command = create).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your reset code is creating *new* `DoubleVar`s, and setting them to the empty string. You're doing nothing to the original variables.

You don't need to use the variables for this, you can simply call the `delete` method on each entry widget:

```
for entry in sd:
    entry.delete(0, "end")
```

Comment: it worked! please, if you don't mind, can you explain the code.